# Angular2 - Cannot change element style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am dynamically giving elements IDs with `*ngFor` like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of questionsBySubCat" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="subcat-container">
        <h4 class="sub-cat">{{ section?.subcategory }}</h4>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let question of section?.questions; let i = index" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-10">
            <h5 (click)="toggleAnswer(question)" class="question">{{ question?.question }}</h5>
            <div class="answer-div" id="ques-{{question?.subcategory.split(' ').join('')}}-{{question?.num}}">
                <br> // DYNAMIC ID HERE ^^
                <p [innerHtml]="question?.answer" class="answer-text"></p>
                <hr>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check the elements in the console the IDs are created correctly.  When I use jQuery to log out the inner html of the element it works perfectly but when I use jQuery to change the elements css (display to none) it does not work at all.  Why is this?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and angular?  ANy way impossible to answer without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Put your jQuery code for changing css elements in setTimeOut() function.

It is not working because you are trying to access dom element and modify their css before they gets created dynamically. So you should let your jQuery code(which change css element) in setTimeOut().

```
 setTimeout(function () {
  $('your dynamic dom element').addClass('in');
 }, 1000);
```

Hope this helps.